# How Do I Create A Setup Project With A Windows Application and A Windows Service?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, windows-services, setup-project

I would like to create a Setup Project in Visual Studio 2008 that installs both a .Net Windows application and a Windows Service.

Is this possible or do I need to create two different Setup Projects?

Comment: You can do it in a VS2008 setup project, but as I recently discovered, if you install a new version of your service over an older version, you're likely to corrupt the installation and have to remove everything manually.  Follow bryanmac's advice and try WiX.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout Wix - it's the standard way to build installers and is very powerful:

> The Windows Installer XML (WiX) is a toolset that builds Windows
>   installation packages from XML source code. The toolset supports a
>   command line environment that developers may integrate into their
>   build processes to build MSI and MSM setup packages.

http://wix.sourceforge.net/

How to install a windows service via Wix:

http://blog.tentaclesoftware.com/archive/2009/01/01/21.aspx